# concating fields with null values

Tags: mysql, concatenation

ill start of by saying "Yes, i know my table does not conform with 1NF."
i am working with something old, and can not change it.
so please, no comments about that.

now, to the problem:

`select title,address,zip,city, concat(telefon1,',',telefon2,',',telefon3) as phone`

the problem with this is, that it works fine until one of the columns in `concat` is null or empty.
if it is, then i get a `Null` result for the phone column.
if all three have values, everything works as expected.

how can i overcome this problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT title,address,zip,city,CONCAT(
    COALESCE(telefon1,''), ',',
    COALESCE(telefon2,''), ',',
    COALESCE(telefon3,'')) as phone
```

Comment: thank you, will select as correct answer in a few minuets.
even due `ifnull` also works, it is a bit slower then your solution.

Comment: @Bohemian: thanks, a good comment from a **great** like you is always accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap each telefon column in `ifnull(...,'')` to turn `null` into blank.

```
select ..., 
    concat(ifnull(telefon1,''),',',ifnull(telefon2,''),',',ifnull(telefon3,'')) as phone
```